# Spring Batch partition doesnt work composite itemprocessor

Tags: spring, composite, itemprocessor

I have a Spring Batch partition job. I’m using `CompositeProcessor`, read data from DB and save these items into an `CopyOnWriteArrayList`. Because the environment is concurrent but my `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is being utilized for other threads and mix information, I don’t know why and what I am doing bad, and the output writing them into files for each thread.

```
public class CustomerItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<beangenerico,CopyOnWriteArrayList<beanCustomer>> {

 private CustomerDAO customerDAO;
 private CopyOnWriteArrayList<beanCustomer> listbean;

 public CopyOnWriteArrayList<beanCustomer> process(beangenerico rangos) throws Exception {

      listbean = customerDAO.getAccAgentes(rangos);

      if(listbean != null) {
          //customer.setId(currentCustomer.getId());
         return listbean;
      }else{
         return null;
         }
    }
```

The configuration of my batch im XML:

```
<batch:job id="partitionJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
      <batch:step id="masterStep">
         <batch:partition step="slave" partitioner="rangePartitioner">
                 <batch:handler grid-size="10" task-executor="taskExecutor"/>
         </batch:partition>
      </batch:step>
</batch:job>

<!-- each thread will run this job, with different stepExecutionContext values. -->
<batch:step id="slave" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
              <batch:tasklet task-executor="taskExecutor" throttle-limit="1">
                 <batch:chunk reader="beaniniendreader" writer="tempRecordsWriter"  processor="completeItemProcessor" commit-interval="1" />
              </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>

        <bean id="taskExecutor"  class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor" />

        <bean id="rangePartitioner" class="my.package.springbatch.RangePartitioner" />  
    <bean id="beaniniendreader" class="my.package.springbatch.FormiikReader" scope="step"></bean>

    <bean id="beanprocessor" class="my.package.springbatch.FormiikProcessor" scope="step">
       <property name="accountExecutiveDao" ref="accountExecutiveDao"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="beanprocessor2" class="my.package.springbatch.CustomerItemProcessor" scope="step">
       <property name="customerDAO" ref="customerAccDao"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="completeItemProcessor"  class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemProcessor">
       <property name="delegates">
           <list>
                <ref bean="beanprocessor2"/>
                <ref bean="accItemprocessor"/>
                <ref bean="beanaccDataItem"/>
           </list>
      </property>
    </bean> 

    <bean id="tempRecordsWriter" class="my.package.springbatch.ListDelegateWriter" scope="step">
       <property name="delegate" ref="flatFileItemWriterPartition"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- csv file writer -->
    <bean id="flatFileItemWriterPartition" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter"
     scope="step" >
      <property name="resource"
     value="file:csv/outputs/users.processed#{stepExecutionContext[fromId]}-#{stepExecutionContext[toId]}.csv" />
         <property name="appendAllowed" value="false" />
         <property name="lineAggregator">
         <bean  class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">
               <property name="delimiter" value="," />
               <property name="fieldExtractor">
               <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
    <property name="names" value="cuenta, name, purchasedPackage" />    
               </bean>
           </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Hello Peter. It would be nice if you looked a little deeper in how to format source code on StackOverflow. I tried my best. It’s also a lot of code for us to wade through. If you cut down the code and limit yourself to a minimal example, you are more likely to attract the attention needed for somebody to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I going back to take the subject of my code, it is advised to me using Threadlocal for storing  thread-specific data  whereby it´s works . Here I put my code again. Thanks for your replies.

```
public class CustomerItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<beangenerico,ThreadLocal<CopyOnWriteArrayList<beanCustomer>>> {
    private CustomerDAO customerDAO;
    private ThreadLocal<CopyOnWriteArrayList<beanCustomer>> listbean = new ThreadLocal<CopyOnWriteArrayList<beanCustomer>>();      

    public ThreadLocal<CopyOnWriteArrayList<beanCustomer>> process(beangenerico rangos) throws Exception {

            listbean.set(new CopyOnWriteArrayList<beanCustomer>());
            listbean = customerDAO.getAccAgentes(rangos);

            if(listbean != null) {

                return listbean;
            } else {
                return null;
            }

    }

    public void setCustomerDAO(CustomerDAO customerDAO) {
            this.customerDAO = customerDAO;
    }
```

}